# PhoneGap Build - How do I Save a file to a mobile device?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, save

I'm new to phoneGap and a novice javascript programmer.  I've created a simple app and it works with phonegap build.  I can upload the file and it gives me an android app or ios app.  What I need to do is make the app save a preferences file.  For example.  I have a setup screen with radio buttons that allow the user to choose things like... If they want a blue or black background in the app, or if they want sound turned on or off.  It works fine until you reload the app and then it goes back to the default settings because I have no option to save the settings.  Is it possible to save the preferences to a text or xml file and save it to the device?  I don't know where to begin or how to even get javascript to create a file to save on a mobile device, or even on my local computer.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use local storage database. It'll help you to save data up to 5 mb. Little things like this can be stored easily.

To save in localstorage use

```
localStorage.setItem("key",value);
```

To get it back

```
mysettingvar1=localStorage.getItem("key");
```

If you still want to save it in a file, there is file plugin. [Installation & documentation are in this link](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.file)

File writing example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>FileWriter Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
    }

    function gotFS(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile("readme.txt", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
    }

    function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
    }

    function gotFileWriter(writer) {
        writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
            console.log("contents of file now 'some sample text'");
            writer.truncate(11);
            writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
                console.log("contents of file now 'some sample'");
                writer.seek(4);
                writer.write(" different text");
                writer.onwriteend = function(evt){
                    console.log("contents of file now 'some different text'");
                }
            };
        };
        writer.write("some sample text");
    }

    function fail(error) {
        console.log(error.code);
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <p>Write File</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you need to set little preferences I believe local storage will be better. Just check preferences in the page load from local storage $ apply css according to it.